# Can't hide status bar on some devices

Tags: java, android

On my device I can successfully hide the status bar by doing the following:

In my manifest I add the following:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SomeActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen"
/>
```

then in my styles:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

---

On my device (Samsung J7 Pro running Android 9), this is the result:

[image: hidden]

As you can see, the status bar and the action bar is hidden. But if I run this on a Huawei P20 Lite, this is the result I get:

[image: not hidden]

At the top there is a black bar where the status bar will be.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `values-v28` folder parallel to `values` folder.

Copy the theme content in new `styles.xml` file and add  `<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>`

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
</style>
```

Also, in Activity class add the following

```
 public class MyActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);
        }
 }
```

Comment: What will happen if the notch display is hidden and you have `shortEdges` set?

Comment: For example, on the Huawei P20 lite, you have an option the hide the notch display.

Comment: You can check the behavior [here](https://proandroiddev.com/making-notch-friendly-apps-for-android-75776272be5c)

Comment: I'm talking about when the user disables notch display in settings, then in my app there will be a black bar where the status bar use to be.

Comment: I believe then notch display will not be the part of the actual display. It will be black.

Comment: @Deˣ Godsend 

Answer (score 2):

Please check this link [making apps notch friendly](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://proandroiddev.com/making-notch-friendly-apps-for-android-75776272be5c&ved=2ahUKEwjjuL7hubzjAhVlmuYKHTC5CzIQjjgwC3oECAIQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3J-v_2Xugdib9lRO3G20vx&cshid=1563383659045). Apparently it is happening because the device has a notch.